# Get current visible chart data after scroll

Tags: javascript, react-native, highcharts

I an using HighCharts HighStock in react-native app and I am trying to get the current visible data of the chart to refresh tooltip with the last visible data, I am already able to have the last value on load since it is the last value of data array but I am failing to get the value after scrolling.

```
events: {
      render() {
        const chart = this;
        points = [];


        Highcharts.each(chart.series, (s) => {
          if (s.visible) {
            const lastPoint = s.points[s.points.length - 1];

            if (lastPoint.y === null) lastPoint.y = 0;
            points.push(lastPoint);
          }
        });
        chart.tooltip.refresh(points);
      },
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Highcharts.find` method and check `isInside` flag in points. If you want to avoid points from a navigator, check `isInternal` flag in series. You should also reset the state of previously hovered points:

```
chart: {
    events: {
        render() {
            const chart = this,
                lastPoints = chart.lastPoints,
                points = [];

            if (lastPoints && lastPoints.length) {
                lastPoints.forEach(function(lastPoint) {
                    lastPoint.setState('');
                });
            }

            Highcharts.each(chart.series, (s) => {
                if (s.visible && !s.options.isInternal) {

                    points.push(Highcharts.find(
                        s.points.slice().reverse(),
                        function(p) {
                            return p.isInside ? true : false;
                        }));
                }
            });

            chart.lastPoints = points;
            chart.tooltip.refresh(points);
        }
    }
}
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xwgs13r6/

**API Reference:**

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts.Point#setState

https://api.highcharts.com/class-reference/Highcharts#.find

Comment: It is only returning the last value of the data array, besides I need to find the last value shown on the screen after scrolling, to check your method I tested it in click event but still returning the last value in the data array. Any idea on how to fix that? and how to get onScroll function. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Ourabi, Which scrolling do you mean? The code works well with using the bottom navigator and scrollbar.

Comment: bottom navigator and scrollbar are disabled for design reasons, It is a mobile app so I am using screen touch to scroll the chart

Comment: @Ourabi - So yes, you're right - the above code will not work in that case. We need to use `scroll` event and get last visible data points by pixel calculation. Please check this example: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/182vkga7/

Comment: Thanks for you answer the problem was that zoom is 100% so all points are visible for Highcharts, I managed to solve it by reducing the zoomed area which led me to an other problem, when I scroll the zoomed area it only renders after I release click on iPhone simulator and when I release the touch on real device, any idea what is causing that? I already noticed that this problem is not occuring on jsfiddle examples. Thanks

Comment: Hi @Ourabi, Please try to increase `cropThreshold` value: https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.cropThreshold

Comment: Thanks for your answer the documentation seems to be the exact thing I am looking for but it is not working, chart still renders only after release. I increased the value of    cropThreshold to 1000.

Comment: @Ourabi - Please provide me with some live example with your code, so that I can test it.

Comment: @Ourabi - Is that issue occurs in Chrome dev tools, in mobile view? Also, please check the result with disabled `dataGrouping`. Example: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/0uqh4akt/

Comment: I disabled `dataGrouping` but still same issue, chart renders only after scroll ends I am having the same problem using Android device, iPhone 6 and all Xcode simulators.

Comment: @Ourabi - I need to reproduce the issue to help you. By using your code everything seems to work fine - please check this video: https://streamable.com/2m7rc

Comment: Ok, thanks! That is a Highcharts issue reported here: https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/6131. You can add your video in a comment.